# Как прикрепить библиотеку к запускаемой программе?

Tags: java, dll

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

С помощью `java` можно запускать стороннее приложение несколькими способами.

Скажите, в есть ли способ при этом внедрить нужную библиотеку в этот новый процесс?

Весь инет перерыл - ничего толкового не нашел.

Вариант с маленькой программой-лоадером, которая будет запускать указанный процесс с приаттаченной указаной либой есть, но мне кажется это огородом.

Так же вопрос - есть ли у кого-то идеи, как средствами джавы редактировать PE-заголовки запускаемого бинарника (конкретно - списки импорта)?

Заранее благодарен за ответы и мысли.

Comment: Допустим, вы смогли внедрить библиотеку в чужой процесс. Но что вам толку с этого? Процесс о библиотеке ничего не знает, и соответственно не будет вызывать её код. Вам нужно ещё и "забрать" управление у программы, и вызвать самостоятельно код библиотеки. Чревато undefined behaviour'ом.

Comment: Хм... А из джавы же нельзя управлять памятью процесса?

В дельфи это делается довольно просто:

`  //записать машинный код по зарезервированному адресу
  WriteProcessMemory(Process, Memory, @inject, sizeof(inject), BytesWritten);
  //выполнить машинный код
  hThread := CreateRemoteThread(Process, nil, 0, Memory, nil, 0, ThreadId);
  if hThread = 0 then Exit;
  CloseHandle(hThread);
`
Исполняет удаленный поток, а большего и не надо - либа проинициализировалась и делает свои дела от имени пациента (в моем случае слайсинг некоторой функции).

В джава такое невозможно?

Comment: А, вы ещё модифицируете бегущий код! Ну, наверняка можно, посмотрите на reflection API и [интерфейс отладчика](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/). Идти мимо официального пути ввиду наличия JIT не советую.

(То, что вы привели, судя по всему, чистый WinAPI.)

Подумайте, однако, о том, что компилятор может заинлайнить почти любую функцию.

Comment: Судя по всему придется опять засесть за дельфи и написать-таки лоадер... Печалит. Разлюбил я его.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов:

(1) WinAPI-шную функцию можно вызвать и из C

(2) Вы не забыли про JIT? Функция может быть скомпилирована в момент первого вызова.

Comment: никак, любые ухищрения сводятся до вызова сторонних програм, этого же результата можно добится вызывая программу из bat/sh файлов. вы для начала обрисуйте задачу в целом. может можно обойтись без этих костылей

Comment: Без костылей не обойтись. Суть: приаттачить либу, которая производит слайсинг некоторой функции пациента, в которую стекается расшифрованный траффик. Дальше поднять сокет по локалхосту на некий порт и пропускать траффик через свой сервер. Можно назвать это сниффером, пожалуй. Вариант "расшифровывать в джаве" не предлагать - крайне проблемматично. Проще написать лоадер.

Comment: Добавьте хоть какой-нибудь ответ, дабы закрыть вопрос уже...